# R: Convert a string from a function input to part of an expression in the function

Tags: r, function, parsing, eval

I'm trying to use a string input for a function that then needs to be converted into useable form in R. For example:

I have the following function:

```
MyFunction <- function(MyDataFrame){ 
Fit <- aov(VariableA ~ A * B * C, MyDataFrame)
model = lme(VariableA ~ A * B * C, random=~1| Sample, method="REML", MyDataFrame)
return(anova(model))
}
```

This works fine. However, I sometimes want to use different formulas with a single function so my "Expression" can be `"A * B * C"` or `"A * C"`. I tried using:

```
MyFunction <- function(MyDataFrame, Expression = "A * B * C"){ 
Fit <- aov(VariableA ~ Expression, MyDataFrame)
model = lme(VariableA ~ Expression, random=~1| Sample, method="REML", MyDataFrame)
return(anova(model))
}
```

This does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `as.formula(paste0("VariableA~",Expression))`

Comment: Use a formula instead of a string, i.e. `Expression = ~ A * B * C` and then use `lme(update(VariableA ~ ., expression))` inside your function. The call to `update` will updated your formula `VariableA ~ .` to `VariableA ~ A * B* C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R needs to know that the formula is actually a formula, and you run into issues with evaluating expressions, environments, and so forth when you have a string that you want to use as an expression in a formula. Based on what it looks like you are trying to do, I would probably set up my function like so:

```r
library(nlme)

fun <- function(df, response, predictors){ 
  model_formula <- as.formula(paste0(response, " ~ ", predictors))
  fit <- aov(model_formula, df)
  model = nlme::lme(model_formula, df)
  return(anova(model))
}

fun(Orthodont, "distance", "age")
#>             numDF denDF   F-value p-value
#> (Intercept)     1    80 3096.4889  <.0001
#> age             1    80   85.8464  <.0001
fun(Orthodont, "distance", "age + Sex")
#>             numDF denDF  F-value p-value
#> (Intercept)     1    80 4226.931  <.0001
#> age             1    80  111.949  <.0001
#> Sex             1    25    4.429  0.0456
```

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, you don't even need to use strings, you could pass the expression directly and use `match.call()` with an `eval()`. A toy example is:

```
fun <- function(data, expression){
  m <- match.call()
  lm(hp ~ eval(m$expression), data)
}


fun(mtcars, cyl)
#Call:
#lm(formula = hp ~ eval(m$expression), data = data)

#Coefficients:
#       (Intercept)  eval(m$expression)  
#            -51.05               31.96
```

Comment: you don't even need the match.call part. you can use `lm(update(hp ~ . , expression), data)` and then call the function like `fun(mtcars, ~cyl)`